# CANoe API for realtime requirement

Tags: python, api, real-time, canoe

I'm looking for a fitting API to send CAN signals via CANoe. I'm pretty familiar with python and found a usable API with the pywin32 package. A Requirement of my project is to guarantee real-time (in this case <20ms) communication. I'm not an expert when it comes to details like latency etc., but as far as I know, python isn't the fastest. Are there any other APIs that secure the real-time requirement or are my concerns unfounded using a python script works fine?

Comment: If a requirement is to guarantee real-time communication, then you shouldn't be running on any regular operating system, but a real-time one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-Time is a very broad buzz word, the question is what is your acceptable response time on all events you want to react on.

E.g. dSPACE has adapted Python to be somewhat real-time capable, so you can run it synchronous with your plant model even at 1ms rate, with very limited code in there.

I am not sure whether there exists e.g. an integration, which allows to write measurement or ECU/ simulation nodes, these are the ones which are theoretically real-time capable in CANoe, in Python or more precise IronPython in this case.

However, this would then be a standard Python not optimized for that and thus probably have issues.

Last, if you really need it fast, you would have to use a Vector hardware, which allows CANoe to offload its runtime/ kernel to the interface processor.

Only the very high end stuff would allow you to install e.g. IronPython, despite they usually run some embedded Windows version.

Comment: In this case the realtime requirement is <20ms and a maximum of 20 system variables need to be read and set.

Comment: @moweigel 20ms and 20 signals does not sound that much. What you could try, but for sure this makes the tooling a bit more complicated, would be to use FDX communication between a Python written server application and CANoe. The FDX would run on your localhost, so should be more than fine.
Your Python application for sure has to minimize garbage collection and whatever can take too much time.